# WakefulBroadcastReceiver startWakefulService fails to proceed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, wear-os, android-broadcastreceiver

My app will not invoke the intentservice request from the wakefulbroadcastreceiver

Manifest:

```
        <service
        android:name=".MyWearableListenerService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED"/>
            <data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".CounterActivity$WearableReceiverService"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name=".CounterActivity$WearableReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
    </receiver>
```

So i register all receivers and services.

inside my main activity i have these as sub-classes within the main class so i can call the method in the main class msgReqAction()

```
public class WearableReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, WearableReceiverService.class);
        startWakefulService(context, service);
    }
}

public class WearableReceiverService extends IntentService {

    public WearableReceiverService(){
        super("WearableReceiverService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        msgReqAction(intent.getIntExtra(MyConstants.BROADCAST_DATA_REQ, 0));
        WearableReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

I don't think having these as subclasses should hinder the situation but it may. if i must have these outside the main class for operation let me know.

finally i begin the whole process from a listener outside the main activity that listens for a message from the wearable

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(final MessageEvent messageEvent) {
    nodeId = messageEvent.getSourceNodeId();
    String incomingPath = messageEvent.getPath();
    int incomingReq = Integer.parseInt(new String(messageEvent.getData()));

    if(incomingPath.equalsIgnoreCase(MyConstants.MSG_COUNTER_REQ_PATH)) {
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction(MyConstants.BROADCAST_ACTION_RESP);
        broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra(MyConstants.BROADCAST_DATA_REQ, incomingReq);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

    }else if(incomingPath.equalsIgnoreCase(MyConstants.MSG_DEFAULT_PATH)){

    }
}

public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION_RESP = "com.example.johnbravado.zionwork.MESSAGE_PROCESSED";
```

my project is com.example.johnbravado.zionwork - also on a side note is there a way to change and refactor that in android studio easily so i can get rid of example or change it completely?

when i run the debugger the system gets all the way to

```
startWakefulService(context, service);
```

then it crashes without entering the intent service. is there somethig simple i am missing amongst all this which is preventing it from going into the service and doing work. best i can tell is it does not go into the service at all. i added some intro lines of the service

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    int data;
    data = 0;
    data++;
    msgReqAction(intent.getIntExtra(MyConstants.BROADCAST_DATA_REQ, 0));
    WearableReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
```

and tried to run debug points on these lines and it didnt get there.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a `Service` defined as a non-static inner class.

A non-static inner class contains a reference to its outer class. This means that in order to create a new instance of the inner class, you need to have an instance of the outer class.

When Android tries to start your `Service`, it tries to create a new instance of the inner class. This fails, because Android does not have an instance of the outer class to use in the creation.

The same rule applies to the `BroadcastReceiver`.

Solution: Move all your inner classes to full-fledged classes (in their own source files).

Comment: Is there anyway I can call that msgReqAction() from an external service. The point of the service to to work with the main activity when the device goes into sleep mode. Or only real way is make some static variables that the service can reference and then in the main activity when onResume() is called do what is needed with what had happened while asleep.

Comment: You can cheat and have the `Activity` store a reference to itself in a `static` variable so that the `Service` can call methods on it. However, this is bad practice. Usually, a `Service` communicates with activities by sending broadcast `Intent`s (that the `Activity` is listening for) or by having the `Activity` bind to the `Service` and providing callbacks from the `Service` to the `Activity` using AIDL or by using something like EventBus (which is a publish/subscribe framework)

Comment: I thought that is what my broadcast receiver is doing. If I exchange the wakefulbroadcast with a normal broadcast and remove the use of a secondary service and just handle the msgReqaction() in the broadcast receiver would that work. Or how would I get a broadcast receiver to work with the main activity if not part of it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused about all your components. Normally you use a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` which will be triggered by the Android framework if the phone may be asleep when something happens that you want to know about (and when your app may not be running). This holds a wake lock while firing up a `Service` to perform further processing. If you only want to catch these events when your app is running, then you should just create an instance of your `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Activity` and register it to listen for the events you are interested in. In this case, the ...

Comment: ... `BroadcastReceiver` can be an inner class, and it doesn't need to be added to the manifest because it won't be instantiated by the Android framework. Please explain how your components are supposed to interact. I'm a bit lost, especially based on the code you've posted.

Comment: i have a simple counter app that counts 6 things which i log as walking down the road. so every 5-10 minutes i want to add to this counter but i dont want to pull out phone instead i just want to use my watch to increment the various counters. since phone will be in pocket it will go to sleep. but i still want to count. i was using live listeners originally and it worked great when phone was on and app was in foreground. as soon as screen went off communication failed, which made me research into all these services and broadcasts so app can work while "sleeping"

Comment: Is this only supposed to happen when your app is running (ie: `MainActivity` started? Or is it supposed to happen all the time?

Comment: When activity is running. I have a button that is supposed to start my wear listener service and then when done stop the service. But for some reason when service is stopped I can still receive send messages. Even though under developer mode active services it doesn't show it.

Comment: I'm still confused, but if you only need this when your app is running, you can keep the `BroadcastReceiver` as an inner class, remove the `<receiver> declaration from the manifest, and register your `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Activity` programatically. You create an instance of the `BroadcastReceiver` using `new WhateverReceiver()` and call `registerReceiver()`. When `onReceive()` is called, you can do whatever you want directly in `onReceive()` (if it doesn't take too much time) and you don't need the rest of the stuff (`Service`, etc.). You don't need a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` for this

Comment: Yes that is what I ended up doing after talking with you and it is working now. I was not having faith in the broadcast receiver at first because I was seeing g examples and people saying to unregister it onPause() I thought sleeping caused onPause to be called which would negate the use of it. But I don't think I unregister the receiver either now that I think about it

Comment: If you want the receiver available when the app is paused, then you don't want to unregister it in `onPause()`, that would defeat the purpose. However, you should unregister the receiver in `onDestroy()`. This prevents memory leaks.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve the problem. Please answer your own question so that others can benefit from your solution. If you also accept the answer this question will be removed from the list of unanswered questions - also a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to eliminate the WakefulfulBroadcastReceiver and secondary IntentService. Instead, I used a BroadcastReceiever and sent a broadcast directly from the Wearable listener function and used that to process data directly within the activity.

```
public class WearableReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Intent service = new Intent(context, WearableReceiverService.class);
        //startWakefulService(context, service);
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                "com.example.johnbravado.zionwork");
        wakeLock.acquire();
        // Do Work
        msgReqAction(intent.getIntExtra(MyConstants.BROADCAST_DATA_REQ, 0));

        wakeLock.release();
    }
}
```

Even though i do not do much that would necessarily require a wakelock. if i decide later to do more work i have it ready to go. i am not sure if this is best place for the wakelock either never really used them but that is another topic.

I removed reference to the extra service and receiver in the manifest file also. works good now